# how to remove the People menu from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am the only user of my computer.  I think the People menu in Chrome is not necessary for me and slow me down.  How can I get rid of it?

I tried to remove all users.  But the menu is still there and I lost all my browing history :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Type this in the omnibox (address bar): `chrome://flags`

Set the option named `Enable new profile management system` to `Disabled`.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for it. It is about halfway down the page. After you are finished, restart Chrome.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/Q0CTWKv6vzw/jbImo3Qr_qMJ)

**Update**

After updating to Chrome version 44 (July 2015) you will notice that this no longer works. Chrome is really wanting to force this on us (against the wishes of most of its users; whether they know it or not). It is still possible to remove (for the moment at least) by using a command line switch:

1. Make a new shortcut for Google Chrome on your desktop
2. Right-click on the shortcut and click `Properties` in the drop-down menu
3. In the textbox for `Target`, add a space at the end of the text already there, and then add the following text: `--disable-new-avatar-menu`
4. Hit `Apply` in the bottom right corner
5. The button should disappear next time Chrome is restarted.

BTW, if they keep it up, I'm going to make another command line modification and replace the first part of that target box with ...`\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`.